how do I fix the issue of "requested modulr not providing an export named 'default' in vue composition API?
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=86b530de' does not provide an export named 'default' (at db.js:1:8)
I was trying to connect to the firebase real time database but my page doesn't get rendered due to that issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
